# Streaming libpq results from PQexec

Tags: c, postgresql, batch-processing, postgresql-9.3, libpq

In attempting to download a large batch of data from Postgres 9.3 in C via libpq's `PQexec`, I'm wondering if there's a way to stream the result set from the server. From watching top, I can see my memory utilization increasing by roughly the expected result set size when I call `PQexec`. I want to iterate over the results and "throw away" the results after I've processed them to keep the memory utilization on the processing node down. I couldn't find any mention of such behavior in the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/libpq-exec.html). Something like psycopg2's [fetchmany](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.fetchmany) would be ideal.

Is the only way to "stream" results from libpq by rewriting the query to run in batches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a recent enough libpq (libpq-5.5 shipping with PostgreSQL 9.2), you may call `PQsetSingleRowMode` as described in [Retrieving Query Results Row-By-Row](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-single-row-mode.html).
`PQexec` will have to be replaced by the asynchronous `PQsendQuery`.

Otherwise a technique that works with all versions is to open a cursor at the SQL level (see [DECLARE...CURSOR](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-declare.html)) and FETCH from it through successive `PQexec` calls until completion. This is how `FETCH_COUNT` is implemented in psql, the command-line tool.
It also has the advantage that other queries can be executed on the same connection while the cursor is opened and the program is still looping over the results.